# Is there any Open source Java based Knowledge Base System

Tags: java

We are building a site, where all the knowledge base articles need to be displayed?

Is ther any Open source Java based Knowledge Base System available? If not, what are the best alternatives?(wiki, cms)

Comment: I'm looking for it too.
I want to do something like this as my university project, but the project manager have no free slots for me :(

Answer (score 1):

Everything's here:
http://java-source.net/
I recommend XWiki or Confluence (but it's not free)
And very powerful solution is Liferay