# Knowledge base frameworks

Tags: java, database, knowledge-management

I need to build and use knowledge base in Java application. Are there any frameworks for Java that allow to do this?

Comment: yes, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727852/is-there-any-open-source-java-based-knowledge-base-system

Comment: I don't mean any collaboration systems. I mean a framework that allows to build machine-readable knowledge bases and generate new knowledge based on predefined rules like described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning

Answer (score 2):

Jess (http://www.jessrules.com) is what I was searching for.